# Firefox closing div too fast

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome, firefox

I've problem with wordpress theme. The code looks different in chrome and firefox so page displays incorrectly.

My code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="large-8 columns">
   ...
    </div>
    <aside class="large-4 columns sidebar-right">
        <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Blog Sidebar") ) : ?> <?php   endif;?>
    </aside> 
</div>
```

In chrome it's okay, aside element is inside the "row" div, but in firefox it's outside the row.

Comment: do you have live link...?

Comment: In Firefox version `61.0.1 (64-bit)` the aside is indeed in the row, at least when tested locally. This leads me to think that it might be something other than what you have posted that is producing those results, possibly something that `dynamic_sidebar()` is doing.